# How to have part of my webpage not print

Tags: css, printing

I am making about 20 pages of a website all with a PDF in the middle and some ads on the sides. When someone prints the page I want the PDF to print, but not the ads on the sides. Is there a way to do this?

This image shows what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: This is what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: One of the pages is here..  http://cthsbc.org/2013%20Sale%20Entry%20Pages/page70.html  I made6 different ID which is probably not the most efficient way but for now i thought it might work...but still the 6 divs (business cards) are still printing =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add specific styles for printing media.

```
@media print {
  .my-advertisments {
      display:none !important;
  }
}
```

The rules inside the `@media` block will be used whenever you're trying to print the page.

Comment: One of the pages is here.. cthsbc.org/2013%20Sale%20Entry%20Pages/page70.html I made6 different ID which is probably not the most efficient way but for now i thought it might work...but still the 6 divs (business cards) are still printing =/

Answer (score 4):

You can have custom CSS for print, so you can simply set the display to `none` on print:

```
@media print {
  #something {
       display:none;
     }
}
```